# hive 1.2 sql returns unexpected special character

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, hive-serde, hdp

Running the following Hive query returns special characters:

```
SELECT t6.amt amt2,t6.color color
FROM(
 SELECT t5.color color, t5.c1 amt
 FROM(
  SELECT t1.c1 c1, t1.c2 AS color 
  from(
   SELECT  7716 AS c1, "Red" AS c2 UNION 
   SELECT  6203 AS c1, "Blue" AS c2
  ) t1
 ) t5
order by color) t6
ORDER BY color
```

It returns the results as

```
amt color
4   �
3   �
```

Is it a known hive bug?

Explain plan

```
    Map 5 <- Union 2 (CONTAINS)
Reducer 3 <- Union 2 (SIMPLE_EDGE)
Reducer 4 <- Reducer 3 (SIMPLE_EDGE)

Stage-0
   Fetch Operator
      limit:-1
      Stage-1
         Reducer 4
         File Output Operator [FS_331359]
            compressed:false
            Statistics:Num rows: 1 Data size: 92 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
            table:{"input format:":"org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat","output format:":"org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat","serde:":"org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe"}
            Select Operator [SEL_331358]
            |  outputColumnNames:["_col0","_col1"]
            |  Statistics:Num rows: 1 Data size: 92 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
            |<-Reducer 3 [SIMPLE_EDGE]
               Reduce Output Operator [RS_331357]
                  key expressions:_col1 (type: int)
                  sort order:+
                  Statistics:Num rows: 1 Data size: 92 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
                  value expressions:_col0 (type: string)
                  Select Operator [SEL_331351]
                     outputColumnNames:["_col0","_col1"]
                     Statistics:Num rows: 1 Data size: 92 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
                     Group By Operator [GBY_331350]
                     |  keys:KEY._col0 (type: int), KEY._col1 (type: string)
                     |  outputColumnNames:["_col0","_col1"]
                     |  Statistics:Num rows: 1 Data size: 92 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
                     |<-Union 2 [SIMPLE_EDGE]
                        |<-Map 1 [CONTAINS]
                        |  Reduce Output Operator [RS_331349]
                        |     key expressions:_col0 (type: int), _col1 (type: string)
                        |     Map-reduce partition columns:_col0 (type: int), _col1 (type: string)
                        |     sort order:++
                        |     Statistics:Num rows: 1 Data size: 92 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
                        |     Group By Operator [GBY_331348]
                        |        keys:_col0 (type: int), _col1 (type: string)
                        |        outputColumnNames:["_col0","_col1"]
                        |        Statistics:Num rows: 1 Data size: 92 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
                        |        Select Operator [SEL_331342]
                        |           outputColumnNames:["_col0","_col1"]
                        |           Statistics:Num rows: 1 Data size: 91 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
                        |           TableScan [TS_331341]
                        |              alias:_dummy_table
                        |              Statistics:Num rows: 1 Data size: 1 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
                        |<-Map 5 [CONTAINS]
                           Reduce Output Operator [RS_331349]
                              key expressions:_col0 (type: int), _col1 (type: string)
                              Map-reduce partition columns:_col0 (type: int), _col1 (type: string)
                              sort order:++
                              Statistics:Num rows: 1 Data size: 92 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
                              Group By Operator [GBY_331348]
                                 keys:_col0 (type: int), _col1 (type: string)
                                 outputColumnNames:["_col0","_col1"]
                                 Statistics:Num rows: 1 Data size: 92 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
                                 Select Operator [SEL_331344]
                                    outputColumnNames:["_col0","_col1"]
                                    Statistics:Num rows: 1 Data size: 92 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
                                    TableScan [TS_331343]
                                       alias:_dummy_table
                                       Statistics:Num rows: 1 Data size: 1 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
```

Can disabling or enabling a configuration parameter help me here?

If I reverse the order of columns in the outer most select then the query returns expected results. I would have expected the result to be

color amt

Blue 6203

Red 7716

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same query on my Hive 2.3 with both MR and Tez and the results are the same as yours. I turned off all the query optimizations, stats gathering and rcp but the result remains the same. The problem is Hive making `order by` on single reducer and since you have two sequential `order by`'s Hive merges them into single reduce stage (it's easy to see if you look and extended or formatted query plans). To be more precise Hive uses `_col0, _col1` etc. for column aliases, in `t5` subquery your key is `_col0` but in `t6` it's `_col1` that's why in select operator you see

```
expressions:: "_col1 (type: string), _col0 (type: int)"
```

and in reduce output operator

```
key expressions:: "_col1 (type: int)"
```

So Hive some how switched key type when the select columns are swapped. If the type order is the same in t5 and t6 then there is no problem

```
key expressions:: "_col0 (type: string)"
```

How to avoid this -- I don't really know as making sequential `order by` in single reducer is not due to extra optimizations.

Comment: Thanks a lot of filing the Jira.